# "Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent"

Tags: php, session, http-headers

Every time I try to start a session on a particular page I get the following error:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at ............ on line 23

using this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        echo "$user";
    }
else
    {
    }
?>
```

Is it suggesting I've already used `session_start();`?

Comment: "(output started at ............ on line 23" Whats on line 23?

Comment: Line 23 is the 'session_start();' bit of the code above.

Comment: In my case I had to set the file encoding without BOM.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

"Headers already sent" means that your PHP script already sent the HTTP headers, and as such it can't make modifications to them now.

Check that you don't send ANY content before calling `session_start`. Better yet, just make `session_start` the first thing you do in your PHP file (so put it at the absolute beginning, before all HTML etc).

Comment: Please allow me to share another insight. If you do PHP documents, ensure that the <?php is the first character, not tabbed or spaced. This solved my issues.

Comment: In my case - I created new document, pasted the contents and works. The problem was that in the file included there was a utf sign (bom) included.

Comment: I needed to change the encoding of my document from UTF-8 to ANSI. UTF-8 has a hidden [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) prior to the start of the file's contents, so that was getting sent before session_start had a chance to do its thing.

Comment: I had same issue as AaronSieb. Changed file encoding to UTF-8 without BOM and everything worked!

Comment: Make sure you are NOT using notepad.exe for saving (editing) such a files. It inserts UTF8 BOM at the very beginning of the file. It usually causes such a php warning with line number 1.

Comment: in my case removing end of line spaces from an include solved the problem;  (vim) :%s#\s\+$##  (also see bryansis2000 above)

Comment: in my case, there was a character "p"before the <?php tag. So the controller file had this in beginning p<?php

Comment: @user1039878 Is that really all I have to do? I have the same problem. Session_start is connected to oauthcallback.php I guess?

Comment: In my case I were using Session_start instead of session_start

Comment: I changed the encoding utf-ascii of my file and it worked.

Comment: @bryansis2010 was searching whats the issue because i have already put the session_start() at top but still that was not working. Your comment solved a huge problem for me.