# session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers > already sent

Tags: codeigniter, session

I knew that this question may mark as duplicate but I can't find my answer from any duplicated post so I decided to post it in my own.

I have a Pages with a session. after all task, there is a button that link into this controller called Profileresult.php but even I do not have a code yet its surprising me that I got this error.

here is the error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /home3/oep2732/public_html/knowyourscore/application/controllers/Profileresult.php:1)
>
> Filename: Session/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 140
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home3/oep2732/public_html/knowyourscore/index.php Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

I created a controller called Profileresult.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Profileresult extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: make sure you have not an empty space before the start of php tag or just put ob_start() in beginning of php code

Answer (score 7):

Check your controller file. Remove any empty space within that file. For example:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Profileresult extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
         //your codes here
    }
}
?>
```

In your IDE, if you don't have any comment on top of `<?php` tag, make sure it is in `line 1`. No empty spaces. Same goes to at the end of `?>` tag. If you have empty spaces after that. Those errors will occurs. I've encounter the same problem as yours. I tried to check my controller file as Aman Maurya said, and yes I have few lines of empty spaces. Removed that, that error not display anymore.

Comment: this fixed my errors thanks, but any details why it does require nothing at first line, and how did you figure it out, it would be so helpful

Comment: Hi Rida, I am not sure why but I believe below link should answer why it is happen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812754/cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-headers-already-sent . How I figured out? I read Aman Maurya comment and tried clear out any empty spaces at the top and at the end of my php file, then the error was gone when refreshed.

Comment: This answer really helped me. I could not imagine even one space can create an error. Thanks for your answer. :)